# Normalizing data error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

When I attempt to run the following command in my jupyter notebook there is an issue when it came to normalizing the data. Below the code is the error message I received.

Code:

```
groupByGender_df = purchase_data_df.groupby([‘Gender’])
gender = purchase_data_df[“Gender”].value_counts()

groupByGender_df[“Price”].sum(),
                           “Normalized Price”: groupByGender_df[“Price”].mean().value_counts(normalize=True)})
summaryTable.head()
```

Error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: ‘<’ not supported between instances of ‘str’ and ‘float’, sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
 result = result.union(other)

RuntimeWarning: ‘<’ not supported between instances of ‘float’ and ‘str’, sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
 index = _union_indexes(indexes)
```

I think that it has to do with the fact that I am trying to combine two dataframes? But I am not sure.

Comment: Can you give a small example of purchase_data_df that could be run? I don't think your code is correct, it has syntax errors...

Comment: hmm not sure if I am on the same page but here is an example of something I was able to run leveraging that data                               

playerCount = purchase_data_df['SN'].count()

Comment: also please include the entire stack trace / error. My guess, looking at this again, is that Price is of mixed datatype i.e. string and int.

Comment: Me and my colleague were thinking that as well and perhaps the assignment did that intentionally so my best guess would be to convert the field to a specific data type?

Comment: This is the entire error message

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py:77: 
RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)
anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:5539: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  index = _union_indexes(indexes)